# Bootstrap grid (or IE compatible CSS grid) for the given layout

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, gridview, bootstrap-4

Can you suggest how to do the following layout without CSS grid, in Bootstrap or IE compatible CSS grid. 
**In large screen** 
head, body on left stacking and image on right covering height of head and body. 
[[— layout in large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmKZk.png)] 
**In small screen** 
Head, image and body stacking, full width; image in middle.
[[— layout in small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7my4.png)]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need bootstrap grid which is compatible with IE browser?

If yes, than try to refer an example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .div
  {
  height:100px;
  }
  .div2
  {
  height:200px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Grid</h1>
  <p>In large screen : head, body on left stacking and image on right covering height of head and body.</p>
  <p>In small screen : Head, image and body stacking, full width; image in middle.</p>          
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 div" style="background-color:orange;">
      Heading-<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 div2 pull-right" style="background-color:green;">
      Image-<br> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 div" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Body-<br> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Try to run the code in browser instead of code snippet to get the actual result.**

Output in large screen:

[image]

Output in small screen:

[image]

Further, you can modify the code as per your own requirement.

If we misunderstood anything from your above description than let us know about that. We will try to correct our self and try to provide further suggestions.